# Plague of darkness: if he was standing, he was unable to sit?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, bo, plagues-makkos

Rashi on [Shemot 10:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9871/showrashi/true) states:

> ויהי חשך אפלה שלשת ימים וגו': חשך של אופל שלא ראו איש את אחיו אותן
>   שלשת ימים. ועוד שלשת ימים אחרים חשך מוכפל על זה, שלא קמו איש מתחתיו.
>   **יושב אין יכול לעמוד, ועומד אין יכול לישב**.‏
>
> and there was thick darkness… for three days, etc.: Thick darkness in
>   which they did not see each other for those three days, and another
>   three days of darkness twice as dark as this, so that no one rose from
>   his place. **If he was sitting, he was unable to stand, and if he was
>   standing, he was unable to sit**.

From the wording, it seems like this inability to stand/sit was because of the **thick darkness**.

**If so:** how does darkness effect the ability to stand or sit?

Also, after 3 days standing - wouldn't they have fallen over by then?

**If not**: was this an additional punishment which came with darkness (i.e. being paralyzed)?

Comment: I read this as the darkness being thick enough that it held them in place (physical constraint, not just paralysis), but I don't have a source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Me'am Lo'ez](http://www.headcoverings-by-devorah.com/BoMeamloez.html):

> The darkness was not like the darkness of night, but was something
>   palpable. Our sages state that it could be felt, just like a coin.
>   (Tanchuma; Shemot Rabbah. The measure of the "thickness of a coin
>   [dinar]" is that which is considered to have substance; see Chulin
>   55b. Rashash on Shemot Rabbah writes that the darkness was like a
>   thick curtain that could actually be felt with one's hands.]) It was
>   not the mere absence of sunshine and moonlight. Rather, it was like a
>   deep black cloud had enveloped all Egypt.

[In general there is a "chakira" (discussion) - I believe from the Rogetchover - whether darkness is simply absence of light or a independent creation ("Yotzer Ohr **Ovoreh Chosech**"). See Torah Sheleima in the Miluyim (1) at the end of Parsahas Bo for an extended discussion on the nature of this darkness.]